# remove the lines in CSV that contain specific pattern on the second field

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, perl, csv

How to remove the lines in .csv file that second field contain the word `content`?

example :

```
ams-hbase-log4j,content:\n#LicensedtotheApacheSoftwareFoundation(ASF)underone\n#ormorecontributorlicenseagreements
ams-log4j,content:\n#\n#LicensedtotheApacheSoftwareFoundation(ASF)underone\n#ormorecontributorlicenseagreements.
ams-site,timeline.metrics.cache.size:150,
```

expected output

```
ams-site,timeline.metrics.cache.size:150,
```

Comment: Warning:  This specific example does not appear to have any embedded commas in the first field.  For example, in `"blah, blah",content:\n ...`, the comma inside the double-quotes is not a field separator.  If someone reads this and has to deal with those, the answer provided here will not work correctly.  Parsing CSV correctly to deal with such non-separating commas is tricky business.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `sed` and to remove the lines that second field contains `content`, you could do:

```
sed '/^[^,]*,[^,]*content/d' infile
```

or to remove the lines which second field **stars** with `content`:

```
sed '/^[^,]*,content/d' infile
```

Answer (score 6):

```
awk -F, '$2 !~ /content/' file.csv
```

If you mean "remove lines where the 2nd field **starts with** "content", then

```
awk -F, '$2 !~ /^content/' file.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

basically what you can do in the easiest way is:

```
cat "/dir/yourfile.csv" | grep -v ",content:" > newcsvfile.csv
```

if you want to use the same file name then you can do:

```
cat "/dir/yourfile.csv" | grep -v ",content:" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "/dir/yourfile.csv"
```

Comment: What does this do if "content" is in the third position of a line?

Comment: that's an assumption if "content:" word will be only in the 2nd field, if it is in different field then the solution would not work and would be different